# Is there a way to tag or version Cloud Storage buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud-cli

I have a shell script which refreshes my emulators data to the latest data from prod.
Part of the script is removing the existing bucket and then re exporting it to avoid the `Path already exists` error.

I know that I can manually add version buckets like `/firestore_data/v1` but that would require me to find out what the last version is from the console and then update the shell script each time I need to refresh the emulators data.

Ideally I would like to be able to run `gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-app.appspot.com/firestore_data@latest`

Is there any way to version storage buckets, or to leave tags that can be used when adding and copying down?

Comment: did you try to activate the object versionning in Cloud Storage? Does it solve your issue? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning

Comment: I did stumble on that page but was slightly concerned about turning it on since I couldn’t limit it to specific buckets but rather my entire Firebase storage bucket. I’m concerned about the extra costs for versioning high frequency updates to application based uploads.

Comment: You can also add a lifecycle on your bucket and keep only, for instance, the 3 last version of each object

Comment: Is it possible to avoid versioning for my Firebase storage bucket entirely and only version the sub paths which contain the backup data? Or will I need to create an entirely new bucket for Firebase backups?